# AngularJs: I want to add a class from an array or list, for each iteration inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have the next array in the scope

```
$scope.colors = [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "yellow",
    "orange",
    "black",
    "purple"
];
```

and I use an ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
```

I would like that for each iteration on that div will be added one of the colors from $scope.colors.
I would like to have it added randomly or by order.

I found that link http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=938 where there is a directive that adds a random class from a list, but I couldn't make it work in the ng-repeat, I paste the code from that example in case could help.

```
app.directive("ngRandomClass", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        ngClasses: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {            

        //Add random background class to selected element
        elem.addClass(scope.ngClasses[Math.floor(Math.random() * (scope.ngClasses.length))]);
    }
}
```

});

```
<div class="test" ng-random-class ng-classes="classes"></div>
```

I know I could create something like myclass1, myclass2, myclass3, etc  using the $index, but would prefer to use more descriptive classes names.

Thank you

Comment: So what is the issue? It should just work fine. You probably have use `classes` instead of `colors`

Comment: I checked it several times and copy-pasted the same code, but couldn't make it work

Comment: Can u prepare a plnkr demo

Comment: It just works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/CAollUtgZJxHCqP6g4id?p=preview

Comment: Yes PSL, can you add it as an answer so I can mark it as valid? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it work, provided you bind the `two-way` bound property properly. Also you could probably reuse the directive attribute name itself for two way bound attribute to avoid adding one more attribute.

Try:

```
.directive("ngRandomClass", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        ngClasses: "=ngRandomClass"
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {            
       //Add random background class to selected element
        elem.addClass(scope.ngClasses[Math.floor(Math.random() * (scope.ngClasses.length))]);
    }
}});
```

and use it as:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <div class="test" ng-random-class="colors">{{car}}</div>
</div>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QB6j3fzcTP9LuihDiT3x?p=preview)**

Comment: But in my code is not working, maybe it's because I have this code inside another directive?. If I just `console.log(ngClasses)` I got: `ReferenceError: ngClasses is not defined`